# How to save multiple plotly plots without jupyter notebook crashing?

Tags: graph, plotly, save, jupyter, scatter-plot

Jupyter notebooks crashing on multiple plotly plots

Here is my code:

```
features = ['energy','loudness','speechiness','acousticness', 'instrumentalness', 'liveness', 'valence', 'tempo','duration_ms']
plots = {}
for cols in features:
    plots[cols] = px.scatter(genre, x =cols, y = 'danceability' , color = 'Genre', log_x=False,size_max=35)
for key in plots:
plots[key].show()
```

Is there a way I can clear the memory each time and save it . Then, hopefully close the plots. I tried savefig but that does not work.

Jupyter notebooks keeps on crashing.

Comment: does jupyter still crash if you only make one plot?

Comment: No, it does not. When I try to unload all these plotly plots, Jupyter notebook goes haywire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think storing all of your plotly.express figures in your `plots` dictionary is causing the Jupyter notebook to run out of memory. If you're okay with saving the plots instead of rendering them in your notebook, you can save them locally on each iteration of the loop.

For example:

```
features = ['energy','loudness','speechiness','acousticness', 'instrumentalness', 'liveness', 'valence', 'tempo','duration_ms']

for cols in features:
    fig = px.scatter(genre, x =cols, y = 'danceability' , color = 'Genre', log_x=False,size_max=35)
    fig.write_html(f"./plot_{cols}.html")
```

Comment: you forgot to add.html.Otherwise, it just gives file where html is not specified. It will open with dead ends.